# New Asus M32BF keeps randomly rebooting & losing Wi-Fi connectivity

Tags: wireless-networking, reboot

The computer—an [Asus M32BF](http://www.asus.com/Desktops/M32AD/)—will just restart in the middle of a work session with absolutely no warning. It is also sometimes unable to find wireless networks after a reboot. Restarting the computer myself usually fixes this, but it's a hassle. It's only 3 days old what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of possible causes that could lead to such issues, really. I'd personally make good use of the warranty, unless I were knowledgeable and had the time to run several tests, that may or may not reveal the culprit. Even if you were to find it, you'd still need, I presume, someone else to solve the problem.

You might want to check the temperature sensors, using Speedfan: http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php.